# Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 using AWSCore and AWSApiGateway framewoks with XCode7 and Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, aws-api-gateway

I've created an API using AWS API Gateway and successfully used its generated SDK for Android. Now, I've been trying to use iOS', but whenever I try to build my application, it generates this error (see a bit of it below).

I've tried everything I could think of (removing and updating PODS, disabling bitcode and adding -objc to "Other Link Flag"), but nothing seems to work. Is anyone having this issue (duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64) with AWSCore and AWSAPIGateway framework?

If so, any tips?

I'm using XCode 7 Beta 6 and Swift 2.

```
duplicate symbol _AWSTMCachePrefix in:
/Users/ademarizu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-ahhunxdrfqrzumhhmclmvjcehetb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAWSCore.a(AWSTMCache.o)
/Users/ademarizu/Dev/workspaces/ios/Myapp/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSTMCache.o)
duplicate symbol _AWSTMCacheSharedName in:
/Users/ademarizu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-ahhunxdrfqrzumhhmclmvjcehetb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAWSCore.a(AWSTMCache.o)
/Users/ademarizu/Dev/workspaces/ios/Myapp/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSTMCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AWSTMCache in:
/Users/ademarizu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-ahhunxdrfqrzumhhmclmvjcehetb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAWSCore.a(AWSTMCache.o)
/Users/ademarizu/Dev/workspaces/ios/Myapp/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSTMCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AWSTMCache in:
/Users/ademarizu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-ahhunxdrfqrzumhhmclmvjcehetb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAWSCore.a(AWSTMCache.o)
/Users/ademarizu/Dev/workspaces/ios/Myapp/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSTMCache.o)
duplicate symbol _awsmtl_loadMTLNSCoding in:
/Users/ademarizu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-ahhunxdrfqrzumhhmclmvjcehetb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAWSCore.a(AWSMTLModel+NSCoding.o)
/Users/ademarizu/Dev/workspaces/ios/Myapp/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore(AWSMTLModel+NSCoding.o)
ld: 746 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve that by removing those libraries (AWSCore.framework and AWSAPIGateway.framework) from "Frameworks" folder.

After that, my application build successfully!